# confusion in percentiles

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, percentile

in definition of percentile, it is said that, some value is in 30th percentile means, 30 percent of the data values are **lower** than the given value. But my confusion is, what if I have 1000 data values, which are all 10, then each percentile is same, and no one is smaller or larger than anyone else. why it is not **lower or equal**? could someone please clarify the concept?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a convention (seen often in standardized test scores) of $99$ being the highest percentile. Why? Because two people who both received top marks cannot both be in the $100$th percentile. So to answer your question: All of the values in your data set fall into the $99$th percentile, that is, they are the greatest value in the data set. The $30$th percentile is empty, because no datum is smaller than $70$% of the other data.